# Export CAML query data into Excel

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, caml-query, jsom

I am using JSOM to fetch the data from SharePoint list and binding into HTML table from JS file. And I would like to export the query(CAML Query) data into Excel, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one jquery solution using which we can export SharePoint list to Excel, Word, JSON, XML, SQL, CSV, TXT or PDF.

[code.msdn.microsoft.com](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Export-SharePoint-List-to-a802fd93)

Here you can get javascript and html code. as well as you can download the solution.

Comment: Vishal ,My entire code for retrieving the sharepoint list items is written in .JS file as i am holding site administrator permissions.I had code below to export the html table to excel which is working fine in chrome but unable to find luck in IE browser.Can you please help me how can i do this.